# How can I to set animation of opening popupbox in material design in xmal?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, popup, material-design

- I have a material design Popupbox in my project, And the opening animation of this Popupbox is shown in the GIF below:

[image]

- But I want the opening animation of this Popup box to be in the form of a GIF below:

[image]

Do I have any chance to implement this change?

I have no idea how to implement this change and this is my Popupbox cod in my project:

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox x:Name="P"  PopupUniformCornerRadius="5" PlacementMode="LeftAndAlignMiddles" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="34" Margin="0,22,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid Height="60" Width="90">
                                    <ToggleButton
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton}"
                                          ToolTip="Lock/Unlock" Cursor="Hand">
                                        <materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOnBackground>
                                            <SolidColorBrush
                                            Color="DarkSlateGray" />
                                        </materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOnBackground>
                                        <materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOffBackground>
                                            <SolidColorBrush
                                            Color="Gray" />
                                        </materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOffBackground>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                </Grid>
                                <Button Content="2"/>
                                <Button Content="3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

Comment: It is quite hard to tell the difference between the 2 Gif , you should explain the problem in the first version .

Comment: @AlexR In the first GIF, the way the pop-up opens is by fading, but in the second GIF, the way the pop-up opens is scaled and from one corner.

Comment: this behaviour is coded in storyboards the style of the popup box, you probably have to create your own versiojn of the style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Popup animation is implemented in the WPF Popup class and is not specific to the MaterialDeisgnThemes library (See [PopupAnimation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/a.html#3c0fff4278e78f7e)). There are four different animation modes that you can set (None, Fade, Slide and scroll). The PopupBox-Style sets the mode to "fade". Unfortunately, none of them will animate the Popup the way you want it.

The only solution I can think of, is to animate the popup content yourself. Since the popup is basically a window that fits its size to its content, you need to animate the `LayoutTransfrom` to scale or translate the popup over time. Here is an example that does more or less what you need:

```
        <mat:PopupBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  PlacementMode="LeftAndAlignTopEdges"
                  PopupMode="Click">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>

            <StackPanel>
                <Grid Width="90"
                      Height="60">
                    <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                  Cursor="Hand"
                                  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton}"
                                  ToolTip="Lock/Unlock">
                        <mat:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOnBackground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="DarkSlateGray" />
                        </mat:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOnBackground>
                        <mat:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOffBackground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" />
                        </mat:ToggleButtonAssist.SwitchTrackOffBackground>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </Grid>
                <Button Content="2" />
                <Button Content="3" />
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:0"
                                                      Value="0" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:0.1"
                                                      Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:0"
                                                      Value="0" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:0.1"
                                                      Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
        </Grid>
    </mat:PopupBox>
```

Comment: Dear Tobias,First, thank you very much for answering my question so beautifully, but unfortunately, I get this message as soon as I debug my project, what is the reason for this?
System.InvalidOperationException: ''[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[0].(2)'.'

Comment: When you get this error, the StoryBoard can not set the specified property. Most likely because you did not specify a default LayoutTransform on the Grid. Have a look at the Grid.Layouttransfrom property in my example.